# Удобочитаемая запись лямбда выражений в javascript

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте! Возможно ли с помощью каких-либо библиотек или встроенных средств сократить запись

```
function(n){return n.color!="green";}
```

до

```
n=>n.color!="green"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[CoffeeScript](http://coffeescriptcookbook.com/), но это не встроенный язык, а "над-язык"

Comment: для надмозга :)

Answer (score 1):

Много букв на английском и решение "а мне нравится": [strobe.cc/js_lambda](http://www.strobe.cc/js_lambda/)

Upd.: рекомендуют [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Это называется [стрелочные функции](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), и в новом стандарте ECMAScript 2015 они добавлены как конструкция языка.

Answer (score 0):

В [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground) возможно определить функцию следующим образом

```
var fn = n => n + 1;
```

этот код транслируется в JavaScript

```
var fn = function (n) { return n + 1; };
```