# В чём отличия между обьявлениями функции ()=> и function() при работе с jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть `<select>` c id='adresses'
При загрузке страницы пытаюсь вывести в консоль всё что есть в select c помощью jquery такой конструкцией

```
$('#adresses option').each( function() {
    console.log(this.text);
});
```

И всё отображается в консоли
Но если использую такую конструкцию

```
$('#adresses option').each( ()=> {
    console.log(this.text);
});
```

Выдает тысячу `undefined`

В чём разница?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/510514/201026

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Удобочитаемая запись лямбда выражений в javascript](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/326821/%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b1%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2-javascript)

Comment: и в довесок: [потеря контекста вызова](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535030/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0) чтобы стало понятно почему не работает

Answer (score 1):

Вас сейчас по перенаправляют, задублируют ваш вопрос, но вопрос останется нерешённым. По простому:

В первом случае `this` будет относится к одному из элементов `$('#adresses option')` поэтому у него есть свойство `.text`

Во втором случае `this` будет относится скорей всего к объекту `window` у которого свойства `.text` нет (подобно тому, как если бы вы вызывали внутри функции `window.text`), поэтому `undefined`

При краткой записи функции `()=> {}`, `this` внутри функции не будет относится к этой функции, а будет относится к контексту выше, в вашем случае к объекту `window`

Comment: На https://learn.javascript.ru/es-function прекрасно написано `Внутри функций-стрелок – тот же this, что и снаружи`

Comment: Про this, как раз во второй ссылке в комментариях под ответом расписано